# Delete record from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects that I get from an api, I get the data but I want to remove the ones that have a finish status after x time.

First I must show all the records, after a certain time the records with FINISH status must be deleted

**I am using vue.**

This is the response I get:

```
[
  {
    "id": "289976",
    "status": "FINISH"
  },
  {
    "id": "302635",
    "status": "PROGRESS"
  },
  {
    "id": "33232",
    "status": "PROGRESS"
  }
]
```

This is the method that obtains the information:

I use setTimeout to be able to delete the records with FINISH status after a certain time

```
getTurns() {
        fetch('ENPOINT', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({id: this.selected}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
                            
            this.turns = data;

            data.forEach(turn => {

                if(turn.status == 'FINISH'){
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.turns = data.filter(turn => turn.status !== 'FINISH');
                    }, 6000);
                }

            });
            
           })
          .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

I have tried going through the array and making a conditional and it works for me, but when I call the method again I get the records with FINISH status again. I need to call the method every time since the data is updated

```
    mounted () {
    this.getTurns();

    setInterval(() => {
        this.getTurns();
    }, 5000);
   }
```

maybe I need to order in another way, or that another javascript method I can use

Comment: Very odd.  You should explain in more detail why you want to have a delay.  Side note, you are mixing and matching setTImout and setInterval here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that you need on CodeSandBox. It sure works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-getdata-and-filter-it-after-delay-6yrj16?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Use filter for your case: `turn => turn.status !== 'FINISH'`

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is exactly what you need. I don't get why you wrap everything in `setInterval` and wait for 5 or 6 seconds.

Why don't you return the filtered data instead?

```js
return data.filter(turn -> turn.status !== 'FINISHED');
```

Comment: Because the finished items should vanish after a few seconds

Comment: It's the business rule, the script should do that

Answer (score 1):

You mistake in this place
`this.turns = data;`

It put `data` in component property `turns` before filter;

Do it after filter:

```js
.then(data => {
  // get before filter
  this.turns = data;
  
  // filter data after 6 sec
  setTimeout(() => {
    data.forEach(turn => {
      this.turns = data.filter(turn => turn.status !== 'FINISH');
    });
  }, 6000)
})
```

Sorry, but I don't understand why you use `setTimeout` inside `fetch`. Do you sure that it necessary?

Comment: I use setTimeout to be able to delete the records with FINISH status after a certain time, I can't think of another way it could be

Comment: @Desarrollador Please, can you write me how page has to behave. First step, second, next and next. I think setInterval(5000) and setTimer(6000) isn't the best way.

Comment: @gurenkov56 the page must call every certain time the method that obtains the data from the endpoint, that's why I use setInterval, the method must show all the data, but after a certain time it must delete the records with FINISH status, that's why I use setTimeout

Comment: @Desarrollador Should the data be updated every 5 seconds?

Comment: @gurenkov56 as possible, but the important thing is that they update from time to time

Comment: @Desarrollador You get fresh data every 5 sec but filter works after 6 sec - illogical. Try set 30000 (30 sec) for setInterval in mounted. It should work better

Comment: @Desarrollador I added timer in my code in answer for your case.

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `setTimeout()` delay if you take the promise as what it is: a promise that some data will be there!

The following snippet will provide the data in the global variable `turns` as soon as it has been received from the remote data source (in this example just a sandbox server). The data is then filtered to exclude any entry where the property `.company.catchphrase` includes the word "zero" and placed into the global variabe `turns`. The callback in the `.then()`after the function `getTurns()` (which returns a promise!) will only be fired once the promise has been resolved.

```js
var turns; // global variable 
function getTurns() {
  return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then(r => r.json()).then(data =>
             turns=data.filter(turn=>!turn.company.catchPhrase.includes("zero"))
          )
          .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
getTurns().then(console.log);
```